# Waiting until another process locks and then unlocks a Win32 mutex

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, ipc

I am trying to tell when a producer process accesses a shared windows mutex. After this happens, I need to lock that same mutex and process the associated data. Is there a build in way in Windows to do this, short of a ridiculous loop?

I know the result of this is doable through creating a custom Windows event in the producer process, but I want to avoid changing this programs code as much as possible.

What I believe will work (in a ridiculously inefficient way) would be this (NOTE: this is not my real code, I know there are like 10 different things very wrong with this; I want to avoid doing anything like this):

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE h = CreateMutex(NULL, 0, "name");
    if(!h) return -1;

    int locked = 0;
    while(true) {
        if(locked) {
            //can assume it wont be locked longer than a second, but even if it does should work fine
            if(WaitForSingleObject(h, 1000) == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
                // do processing...
                locked = 0;
                ReleaseMutex(h);
            }
        // oh god this is ugly, and wastes so much CPU...
        } else if(!(locked = WaitForSingleObject(h, 0) == WAIT_TIMEOUT)) {
            ReleaseMutex(h);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If there is an easier way with C++ for whatever reason, my code is actually that. This example was just easier to construct in C.

Comment: Use an event (`CreateEvent`) as well, and the producer can set that to let your other process know it's time to process the data.

Comment: Actually, depending on how the producer is written, your code may deadlock.

Comment: This is a fundamentally broken approach.  Not only do you burn 100% core, you can also *completely* miss seeing that another thread actually acquired and released the mutex.  There is no way forward with this, you need to redesign your approach.

Comment: I know that this approach is an awful one. Events would be 100% better. BUT I want to avoid changing the producers code at all. My question may have not been worded well. What I meant to ask is if there is a way to tell when a mutex is locked/unlocked without doing something stupid like the example I gave.

Comment: Instead of checking the mutex, can you check the "associated data" to see if anything seems to have changed?  You already have "do processing" so I assume you can access the produced data.  The question is, what form is the data in and can you detect if new data has been produced?  If you think new data has been produced, you can obtain the mutex and process the data.

Comment: i could, but the data is over 2 MB, which would not be very quick to process. probably better than constantly checking a mutex, but not by much.

Comment: But is the new data appended to the end or just scattered throughout that 2MB?  Not knowing your data format, it's hard to say how you could proceed.  Is the data in a file?  Does the file last modification time get updated every time there is a change?

Comment: its a shared block of memory with 2 raw (no encoding at all) images. each raw image is about 1MB. nothing in this data SPECIFICALLY signals that there was a change made.

Comment: 2MB is not much to process.  You could just wake up at a fixed interval (like once per second) and checksum/hash the 2MB of data to see if the contents have changed.  I don't know how responsive you need to be, but you could make the interval smaller if you want (like 60 times per second).  It shouldn't take too much cpu power to checksum/hash a 2 MB block of memory.

Comment: that would work, but I feel like only as a last resort. I want to avoid wasting the CPU consistently a little more than I want to avoid changing the producer code.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to avoid changing the producer if **efficient** sharing is needed.  Your design is fundamentally flawed for that.

A producer needs to be able to signal a consumer when data is ready to be consumed, and to make sure it does not alter the data while it is busy being consumed. You cannot do that with a single mutex alone.

The best way is to have the producer set an event when data is ready, and have the consumer reset the event when the data has been consumed.  Use the mutex *only* to sync access to the data, not to signal the data's readiness.

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE readyEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, "ready");
    if (!readyEvent) return -1;

    HANDLE mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, "name");
    if (!mutex) return -1;

    while(true)
    {
        if (WaitForSingleObject(readyEvent, 1000) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            if (WaitForSingleObject(mutex, 1000) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            {
                // process as needed...
                ResetEvent(readyEvent);
                ReleaseMutex(mutex);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you can't change the producer to use an event, then at least add a flag to the data itself. The producer can lock the mutex, update the data and flag, and unlock the mutex.  Consumers will then have to periodically lock the mutex, check the flag and read the new data if the flag is set, reset the flag, and unlock the mutex.

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, "name");
    if (!mutex) return -1;

    while(true)
    {
        if (WaitForSingleObject(mutex, 1000) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            if (ready)
            {
                // process as needed...
                ready = false;
            }
            ReleaseMutex(mutex);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So either way, your logic will have to be tweaked in both the producer and consumer.

Otherwise, if you can't change the producer at all, then you have no choice but to change the consumer alone to simply check the data for changes peridiodically:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, 0, "name");
    if (!mutex) return -1;

    while(true)
    {
        if (WaitForSingleObject(mutex, 1000) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            // check data for changes
            // process new data as needed
            // cache results for next time...
            ReleaseMutex(mutex);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so what I'm hearing is I cant avoid changing the producer if I want it to not be done stupidly. got it. How do you mean use a semaphore instead for supporting multiple clients with events (if I'm changing the producer I may as well do it right)?

Answer (score 0):

Tricky. I'm going to answer the underlying question: when is the memory written?

This can be observed via a four step solution:

1. Inject a DLL in the watched process
2. Add a vectored exception handler for `STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION`
3. Set the guard page bit on the 2 MB memory range (finding it could be a challenge)
4. From the vectored exception handler, inform your process and re-establish the guard bit (it's one-shot)

You may need only a single guard page if the image is always fully rewritten.